# Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) breaks d3 charts

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js

After updating chrome to the latest version 57.0.2987.133, suddenly my charts are broken.

The reason for this is that `.style("height")` always returns 0px.

```
d3.select('#bntextrefmeteo').style("height")
```

This gives the correct results, though:

```
d3.select('#bntextrefmeteo').style("width")
```

D3 version used is: "d3": "4.7.3".

Have a look at this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpoQXw) or the following Stack Snippet for a working demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("#svgContainer").append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("width", "500")
    .attr("height", "100")
    .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);
var bncharts = svg.append("g").classed("bnchartsmeteo", true);

bncharts.append("text").text("Bn Chart Reference").attr("id", "bntextrefmeteo").attr("class", "ref-text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 20)");

var textHeight = bncharts.select("#bntextrefmeteo").style("height");
var textWidth = bncharts.select("#bntextrefmeteo").style("width");

var message = "Height:" + textHeight + ", Width:" + textWidth;

d3.select("#outputDiv").text(message);
```

```css
.ref-text{
  font-size:18px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<b>SVG</b>
<div id="svgContainer">
  
</div>

<b>OUTPUT:</b>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Above snippet in the latest stable release of Chrome i.e. 57.0.2987.133 shows height 0px, but if you try it on any different browser say Safari then it will give the correct value.

**UPDATE:**

This is working:

```
d3.select('#bntextrefmeteo').node().getBoundingClientRect().height
```

Comment: Report Chrome bugs to Chrome's bugtracker. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Reported to chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=708101

Comment: Fix for bug has been landed. It changes Chrome behavior to be similar to Firefox. d3 charts needs to be modified to work in Chrome, Firefox and IE.